# Where to spend chronoboost once you saturated with probes?

Tags: starcraft-2

Usually, during **early game** I spend Chronoboost on probes, warpgate research, upgrades (attack, defence). In general, till 10th minute mark my Nexus's rarely have 100 energy.

In **mid game**, I don't chronoboost probes as much, and even though I still speed-up upgrades... and sometimes units - I don't use it in full.

Where should I spend chronobost in **late game**? I should not worry too much about it just build more guildings and keep pumping army?

Any advise is welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to give us a build you want advice on? My answer is very vague because it's easier to provide you with advice if I know what build you're following, what tech you're going into, etc.

Comment: Last time I prefer FFE in PvZ or 1-2 gates expand in PvP/PvT. If you can advise - that would be awesome! From the other side, in late game I only see value to chronoboost upgrades, sometimes stargates... but with these only sinks of chronoboost I usually have nexus's energy at 100% level. That bothers me

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you really *need* at that moment. Chronoboosting your upgrades is never a bad idea and if you've got your macro under control and you time the chronoboosts right, you can usually chrono one update atleast 3-4 times.

Late-game, you will usually be chronoboosting your stargate, robotics and your upgrades. Only chrono-boost your Warpgates if you've got spare energy.

A useful hint: Chronoboosting a warpgate makes it recharge faster. 
Also, to make chronoboosting much easier, bind all your Nexuses on one key.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Even though you could have 3 stargates late-game, you can use chronoboost to make phoenix faster if you see a muta switch, or to replace colossus faster.  Mid-game boosts should be on upgrades, which allows you to keep an upgrade advantage until the late-game

Answer (score 1):

Midgame is tricky. Get a good scout and determine if you have enough units to withstand theirs. If you do, chronoboost your upgrades and get an upgrade advantage. Most of the time, I attack if I know my upgrades are going to finish and I'll have an upgrade advantage. It makes a big difference.

Late game, most of my upgrades are done and I need my big units out there. If I see a nexus with full energy on it, I'll usually spam chronoboost on a ton of gateways for backup units in case I need them really fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already saturated, when in doubt, chronoboost your upgrades for an earlier advantage.  However, many players waste a ton of extra chronoboost mana - if you are saturated and piling up minerals/gas, don't be afraid to chrono all your production buildings, including gateways, and pump out an extra round or two to soak up your cash.  Also, add more gateways if you're piling up money :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest dump of chrono is to build your army up. Warp in on all your gates, then chrono all your gates, then warp in on all your gates again.

Also a good mineral / gas dump.